# Django 500 Internal Server Error with Passenger on Dreamhost

Tags: python, django, passenger, directory-structure, dreamhost

I'm trying to migrate my fully working Django 1.9.6 project with Python 2.7.3 to Dreamhost. I'm not sure if my current file structure is correct, as well as my passenger_wsgi.py and project.fcgi files.

When I try to access the website I get a 500 Internal Server Error message.

**Here's my directory structure**

```
home
    user
        website.com
            .htaccess
            env
                bin
                include
                lib
                local
            public
                assets
            passenger_wsgi.py
            manage.py
            project.fcgi
            django-project
                settings.py
                urls.py
                wsgi.py
            django-app
```

**Here's my passenger_wsgi.py**

```
import sys, os
cwd = os.getcwd()

sys.path.append(cwd)
sys.path.append(cwd + '/django-project')

if sys.version < "2.7.3": os.execl("/home/user/website.com/env/bin/python",
"python2.7.3", *sys.argv)

sys.path.insert(0,'/home/user/website.com/env/bin')
sys.path.insert(0,'/home/user/website.com/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django')
sys.path.insert(0,'/home/user/website.com/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages')


os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "django-project.settings"

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

**Here's my django-project.fcgi**

```
import sys, os

sys.path.insert(0, "/home/user/website.com/env/bin/python")

os.chdir("/home/user/website.com/django-project")

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "django-project.settings"

from django.core.servers.fastcgi import runfastcgi
runfastcgi(method="threaded", daemonize="false")
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong? This is my first time launching a website like this so I may be making a fundamental directory structure mistake.

Let me know if I should provide any other files or information.

Comment: use `DEBUG = True`

Comment: Also, can you specify which of the DreamHost products you're using? Things are radically different if you're using shared hosting, vps or cloud.

Comment: Setting DEBUG to True still gives the same 500 error. I think I made a mistake in setting up the file structure in the server. I'm using DreamHost's shared hosting.